# is redudant to use `__all__` and `import specific_module`?

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

#### Background

Reading the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/what-does-all-mean-in-python), and looking at the Pandas and Django repository.

If `__all__` is defined then when you `import *` from your package, only the names defined in `__all__` are imported in the current namespace.

I immediately draw the conclusion that if I use `import package.specific_module`, then there is no benefit of defining `__all__`.

However, digging around some common project like Pandas, Django... I realised that developers import specific modules **and** pass all of them as a list to the `__all__` variable, like the below example:

```py
from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (
    DataFrameGroupBy,
    NamedAgg,
    SeriesGroupBy,
)
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import GroupBy
from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import Grouper

__all__ = [
    "DataFrameGroupBy",
    "NamedAgg",
    "SeriesGroupBy",
    "GroupBy",
    "Grouper",
]
```

#### Question

I know that `pydocs` will ignore modules that aren't in the `__all__` variable.
But besides that, what are the other benefits of importing specific modules from within `__init__.py` and at the same time pass them as a list to the `__all__` variable? isn't it redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see [the commit that introduced this code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/2c4df98b547c3c4459d2b403c04a62113a91f0ff#diff-f1133c8d1eb82ff8fa48ff78dbed1cf20c7626a4975c411cbe6301bc7534d36d), you'll notice that this style of coding will not trigger the [Flake8 rule "Module imported but unused (F401)"](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/F401.html), thus leading to a cleaner code. In my opinion, it is easier to understand the purpose of the `__all__` declaration than to understand those `noqa` pragmas at the imports.

By the way, the commit message itself states the intent clearly, it says:

> Removed "# noqa: F401" comments ([#30832](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/30832))
>
> Implemented __all__ for each changed file

And here's the relevant part of the commit:

```
diff --git a/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py b/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py
index 252f20ed40068..0c5d2658978b4 100644
--- a/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py
+++ b/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py
@@ -1,7 +1,11 @@
-from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
-    DataFrameGroupBy,
-    NamedAgg,
-    SeriesGroupBy,
-)
-from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import GroupBy  # noqa: F401
-from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import Grouper  # noqa: F401
+from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
+from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import GroupBy
+from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import Grouper
+
+__all__ = [
+    "DataFrameGroupBy",
+    "NamedAgg",
+    "SeriesGroupBy",
+    "GroupBy",
+    "Grouper",
+]
```

At the end of the day, we're all trying to write code that's easier to read by both programmers and our code quality tools.